# Using a for loop to find IQR in iris

Tags: r, for-loop

I'm trying to use a for loop to find the IQR of the first 4 columns in the iris dataset.

I have tried this:

```
for(IQR in iris[,1:4]){
print(IQR(iris[,1:4]))
}
```

But I only receive an error.  I know there are easier ways to do this for example apply() and sapply(), but I would like to know how to use the for loop because I have no experience with it and I want to see how it would work.  Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

i iterates from 1 to 4

call the ith column with data[,i]

```
for(i in 1:4){
  print(IQR(iris[,i]))
}
```